# Jenkins build error: Cannot find Docker volume

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am running jenkins on docker.I am using windows 11 to run docker

I used below commands for creating jenkins image on docker.

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

while I was trying to create docker image for my springboot application as a freestyle project in jenkins I encountered the below problem

```
[ne-demo] $ docker build -t user5880/hello --pull=true /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne-demo
ERROR: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne-demo"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne-demo"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:254)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:223)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:997)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:509)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:489)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.buildAndTag(DockerBuilder.java:373)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:311)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 20 more
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I configured Docker,Maven,JDK in jenkins dashboard .

I am new to platform and trying to learn dockerising the spring boot application.

Dcokerfile I created

```
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/hello-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar hello-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/hello-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

Can Someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/

You shold `mount` :

```
docker run --name jenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

And the path of `hello-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file is incorrected.
It should be:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","./hello-1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

Comment: I tried the same steps.Still no change ,I created docker volume in my desktop and tried to do maven install then docker build even then its showing the same error